# as if usage - whether it's "statement as if" or "subjuctive as if," it does not matter?

Tags: tense, usage, subjunctives

According to my understanding there are two different types of usages in terms of "as if"/"as though".

One is subjuctive mood and the other just functions like a normal statement.

I think nowadays both usages are acceptable, am I right?

The difference seems to lie in the possibility of the thing happenning, but it seems not to matter to many people.

Here are some examples

**Normal statement as if**

**Example 1**

Past

> He is buying stuff as if he won the lottery.

**Example 2**

Present

> He is buying stuff as if he is the lottery winner.

**Example 3**

Future

> He is buying stuff as if he is going to win the lottery.

**Subjunctive as if**

**Example 4**

Past

> He is buying stuff as if he had won the lottery.

**Example 5**

Present

> He is buying stuff as if he were a lottery winner.

**Example 6**

Future

> He is buying stuff as if he were going to win the lottery.

Comment: Your examples 4-6 are not subjunctive. In Ex 6 for example, "were" is 'irrealis' mood -- it can be replaced with the less formal "was" with no change of meaning

Answer (score 1):

All of the example sentences are grammatically valid, and any might be said by a fluent speaker. The verbs have differences in tense and aspect, of course, but I would not speak of these as having different types or forms of "*as if*". I am curious where you read or learned that. I would say that  "*as if*" is performing the same role or function in each example.